# Lisp error while using ede-cpp-root-project

Tags: emacs, cedet

I've been trying to get the CEDET working with a simple project for the last little while. I have the following project file:

```lisp
(ede-cpp-root-project "aesalon-project"
                :name "aesalon-name"
                :file "~/projects/aesalon/SConstruct"
                :include-path '("/"
                                "/include/"))
```

I've been loading the above into a buffer and executing the buffer contents. The problem is not with the project not loading correctly -- it seems to bet set up properly; I can change the settings etc. using the menubar. When I try to rescan the project's files, however, I get the following error:

```lisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument class-p ede-cpp-root)
  signal(wrong-type-argument (class-p ede-cpp-root))
  child-of-class-p(ede-cpp-root-project ede-cpp-root)
  object-of-class-p([object ede-cpp-root-project "aesalon-project" nil "aesalon-name" "1.0" "/home/ethereal/projects/aesalon/" 3546321 "/home/ethereal/projects/aesalon/SConstruct" nil nil nil unbound unbound "" "" "" "" "" "" ("debug" "release") "debug" nil ("/" "/include/") nil nil nil "\\.\\(h\\(h\\|xx\\|pp\\|\\+\\+\\)?\\|H\\)$\\|\\<\\w+$" nil] ede-cpp-root)
  ede-toplevel-project("~/projects/aesalon/")
  ede-rescan-toplevel()
  call-interactively(ede-rescan-toplevel nil nil)
```

I find this somewhat odd, as when I look at the documentation for [`ede-cpp-root-project`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ede/ede_002dcpp_002droot_002dproject.html) I see that it has `ede-project` as its parent, not `ede-cpp-root`? Or am I misunderstanding the trace? I'm not very familiar with Emacs Lisp.

Here's my output from cedet-version:

```
CEDET Version:  1.0
            Requested   File        Loaded
  Package       Version     Version     Version
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  cedet:        1.0     ok      ok
  eieio:        1.3     ok      ok
  semantic:     2.0     ok      ok
  srecode:      1.0     ok      ok
  ede:          1.0     ok      ok
  speedbar:     1.0.3       ok      ok
  cogre:        1.0     ok      Not Loaded
  cedet-contrib:    1.0     ok      Not Loaded



C-h f cedet-version RET
  for details on output format.
```

And my emacs version: (latest from Arch Linux repositories)

```
GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.9) of 2012-02-01 on shirley.hoetzel.info
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could go about fixing this issue? Is it a problem with my project? My CEDET environment? Version of emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is inconsistencies in EDE and CEDET. As best I can tell, the version of the CEDET that I was using was relying on an old architecture of EDE that has since been changed.

Compiling the CEDET from the latest source tree instead of the (older) snapshot I was using fixed the problem.